# Parse Background job not saving text file?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, background, parse-cloud-code

I try to fetch text from an external website, then save the text to Parse storage as a file.
I thought saving a text file is a very common usage, but I get the error log message "*Creating a Parse.File from a String is not yet supported*".
Here are the codes:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("fetcher", function(request, status) {
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://website.com/text.html',
  followRedirects: true
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    var name = "html.txt";
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, httpResponse.text);
    parseFile.save().then(function() {
        console.log("save file success");
      }, function(error) {
        console.log("save file failed");
      });

  status.success('ok');
}, function(httpResponse) {
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
  status.error('error');
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse file takes either a byte array, or a base64 encoding of a string. Encoding can be done using a Buffer in nodejs...

```
var base64Text = new Buffer(httpResponse.text).toString('base64');
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, base64Text);
```

Comment: It's a workaround to go through, but still confused the plain text does not work.

Comment: I think the reason they don't support text is that it is ambiguous relative to encoding.